# Math project involves cars?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-numbers, mathematical-modeling

I have been searching for a topic that involves math(calculus, modeling, maybe complex numbers) and cars for over 2 months, I already past the deadline but I didn't give up. Please and I would say it again please give me some ideas or topics I can talk about involving the two because I want to do my project involving something I enjoy and at this point, it's cars. I have found some topics but I don't know how good or bad are they and none of the stack exchange members have been helping: maybe measuring the cooling down of a car a good example?/"Fuel efficiency is a function of (among other factors) the speed of the car. We can use mathematics to map this relationship and using it, estimate optimal speed and suggest refueling strategies." which I took out of Reddit.

Comment: You can use mathematical models to model traffic flow?

Comment: You can use math to calculate how the distance for a full stop increases when increasing the initial speed... or you can use Lie brackets to prove that every car can drive sideways...

Comment: If I also do probably the downforce of a car would that be easy or hard for me as a high school student?

Comment: Check out the book "Fast Car Physics," by Chuck Edmondson. There's some math in there for you to ponder.

Comment: I am thinking on doing the doppler effect

Comment: and sonic boom does that have calculus